# Render Django AuthenticationForm in Jinja2

Tags: django, jinja2

I have installed Jinja2 for Django 2.1 and it works fine for j2 templates. I'm trying to render standard AuthenticationForm via following j2 template:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
    {{ csrf_input }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't display the form. Just the button.

[Login form rendered via Jinja2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDvrH.png)

Equivalent for Django template works fine:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

[Login form rendered via Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwhpQ.png)

Can you advise?

Comment: IIRC jinja2 needs the parentheses for function calls so `{{ form.as_p() }}` probably works.

Answer (score 1):

By pure accident I actually tried `{{ form }}` and it worked. It's because `form` points to `form.as_table()` with parentheses as Fynn has pointed out. Now it works. Thanks!